# How do I tell swagger that parameter dataType is an array of objects?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, swagger

I am annotating action method with `@ApiImplicitParams`

```
new ApiImplicitParam(
    dataType = "Array[Model]", // <- What should I write here?
    paramType = "body",
    name = "body",
    required = true,
    allowMultiple = false,
    value = "The JSON array of messages to be logged.")
```

`[LModel` does not work as well.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to use `dataTypeClass` field, instead of `dataType`.

```
new ApiImplicitParam(
  dataTypeClass = classOf[Array[Model]],
  paramType = "body",
  name = "body",
  required = true,
  value = "The JSON array of messages to be logged.")
```

Comment: looks like this property does not exist in swagger.core 1.5.8 which is referenced by swagger-play 1.5.3

Comment: yes, it seems to be added in swagger-core 1.5.13, that should be available in swagger-play 1.6.0 (only for play-2.6.x and above)

Comment: swagger-play 1.6.0 is based on swagger-core 1.5.12, so it this property is not available too